# dynamic php menu with hidden sub-categories only showing when the category name is clicked

Tags: php, menus, css, html

This is for a wordpress store and I want to show the categories names automatically, but with the sub-categories hidden, the code below works perfectly with the hover effect, now I wish to have the click effect instead. The $cats variable is to use the get_terms() function, but for here to work everywhere I had included a few categories, the categories only go so far as the "third generation".

```
<?php $cats = array(array('first', 'sub-first', 'sub-sub-first'),
                    array('second', 'sub-second'),
                    array('third', 'sub-third', 'sub-sub-third')); ?>
<h3>Categories</h1>
<ul class="ul1"> <?php
  foreach($cats as $cat):
    if (isset($cat[0])): ?>
      <li class="li1" onclick="test()"><a href="#"><?php echo $cat[0] ?></a> <?php
        if (isset($cat[1])):?>
          <ul class="ul2">
            <li class="li2"><a href="#"><?php echo $cat[1] ?></a> <?php
              if (isset($cat[2])):?>
                <ul class="ul3">
                  <li class="li3"><a href="#"><?php echo $cat[2] ?></a> </li>
                </ul> <?php
              endif; ?>
            </li>
          </ul> <?php
        endif; ?>
      </li> <?php
    endif;
  endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<style media="screen">
  ul{
    list-style: none;
  }
  a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
  }
  a:hover{
    color:#EF7522;
  }
  .li1{
    background:#1B2332;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid lightgreen;
    padding:10px;
  }
  .ul2, .ul3{
    display:none;
  }
  .li1:hover .ul2{
    display:block;
  }
  .ul2:hover .ul3{
    display:block;
  }
</style>
```

for the click effect I had remove from the style the last two hover effects and add the javascript function test();

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
        $(".ul2").css({
            "display":"block"
        });
    } 
</script>
```

What is happening is that I click a category and all sub-categories are showing, What I wanted is the same as the hover effect, that if I click the first category, I have only the sub-categories of that category and so on.

If someone could help me, I have been twisting my mind over this for a few days already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I went for a different approach, in this case with radiobuttons.
It is working and it is 95% the result desired.

```
<?php $cats = array(array('first', 'sub-first', 'sub-sub-first'),
                    array('second', 'sub-second'),
                    array('third', 'sub-third', 'sub-sub-third')); ?>
<label>Categorias</label> <?php
foreach($cats as $cat):
  if (isset($cat[0])): ?>
    <div class="div1">
      <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $cat[0] ?>" name="age" value="30">
      <label for="<?php echo $cat[0] ?>"><?php echo $cat[0] ?></label> <?php
      if (isset($cat[1])):?>
        <ul class="ul2">
          <li class="li2">
            <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $cat[0] ?>" name="SUB" value="60">
            <label for="<?php echo $cat[1] ?>"><?php echo $cat[1] ?></label><?php
            if (isset($cat[2])):?>
              <ul class="ul3">
                <li class="li3"><a href="#"><?php echo $cat[2] ?></a> </li>
              </ul> <?php
            endif; ?>
          </li>
        </ul> <?php
      endif; ?>
    </div> <?php
  endif;
endforeach; ?>
<style media="screen">
  ul{
    list-style: none;
  }
  a{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  a:hover{
    color:#EF7522;
  }
  .div1 ul{
    display:none;
  }
  .div1 input:checked ~ ul {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```